# How to combine multiple row vectors into a single row vector using loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

```
A= [1 2 3 4  
    2 3 4 5  
    4 5 6 7  
    .  
    ....]
```

where each of the rows is stored in a separate vector as such

```
a1 = [1 2 3 4]  
a2 = [2 3 4 5]  
.  
.  
.  
an = [1 2 3 4]
```

and I need to create new cells, using a loop, containing all previous row vectors as follows:

```
vectors = {a1, a2, a3, ......,an}
```

in the workspace I get `vectors` as a `1 x n` cell and in each cell containing its own vector; e.g. the first cell contains vector `a1`, the second cell contains vector `a2`, etc. I don't want to copy the code every time I have a different number of vectors, so I'd like to automate this.

[image]

Comment: Where do you `a1` to `an` vectors come from? Are you generating them in your code? It makes much more sense to alter the code that generates them than to aggregate them after the fact.

Comment: somebody edited my question in first place as now the question is useless as is fairly simple to concat matrices. i need as i put the question first to create an array of vectors with each vector in his own cell as I can do it manually

Comment: Not really, since the usage of those dynamic variables makes it harder than usual. I read all the revisions to your question and I now see where the confusion stems from; you wanted "a row vector `vectors = {a1,...,an}`. Textually you state "row vector", which is what the original editor changed to; syntactically you want to create a cell. Sorry for rolling back your question, I was confused by the ambiguity. Also: you know you can edit comments instead of posting 4 comments with half a sentence each?

Comment: vectors = {a1,a2,a3} but i need to add these vectors for an unknown number or vectors and i can't figure out
sorry every time i press enter is just creating a new comment

Comment: @Sardar_Usama please take more care with your edits, this is at least the second time I have seen you assume the OPs intent and make changes based on this. In this case you [harmed the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37393178/2) by changing `{}` to `[]`, which is a completely different data type in MATLAB. If you don't understand the language, do not edit the code. Also shame on [the reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12445836) for approving...

Comment: I wanted to make it easier to put my data in the  vectors array instead of typing all the the time v = {a, b, c, ....}

Comment: I put a new question explaining better off.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama that just means that reviewers who don't speak MATLAB saw a lot of good grammar changes and approved it. Whilst I agree with you on the ambiguity, technically a `1 x n` cell is a row vector as well. Do take care to not interpret the OPs meaning when you edit, and refrain from editing code other than to properly indent it at all times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to not hand-copy each row into a separate variable before doing this. The proper way using your desired `for` loop would be thus

```
A = rand(15,39);
vectors = cell(1,size(A,1)); % initialise output

for ii = 1:size(A,1) % loop over all rows
    vectors{1,ii} = A(ii,:); % store each row in the cell
end
```

To do this without a loop (thanks to [@beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker))

```
B = mat2cell(A, ones(1,size(A,1)), size(A,2)).';
```

though a matrix (so your original `A`) would be the best overall, since MATLAB works best with matrices.